# Proof of derivability

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I'm a beginner at mathematical logic and I've come across the following problem:

**Let $X, Y \subset \mathcal{F}$, where $\mathcal{F}$ is the set of all formulas, and assume that $X \cup \{ \lnot \alpha ; \alpha \in Y\}$ is inconsistent. Then there exist $\alpha_0, \ldots, \alpha_n \in Y$ such that $X \vdash \alpha_0 \lor \ldots \lor \alpha_n$.**

I've tried to do a proof by contradiction as follows but didn't get very far:

We may assume that $X$ is consistent (otherwise the statement is obvious by definition of inconsistency). Assume now that for any $\alpha_0, \ldots, \alpha_n \in Y$ we have $X \nvdash \alpha_0 \lor \ldots \lor \alpha_n$, which is equivalent to $X \vdash \lnot \alpha_0, \ldots, \lnot \alpha_n$.

Assume that $Y$ is countable and let $(\alpha_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}_0}$ be an enumeration of $Y$. Then we have for every $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$ that $X \vdash \lnot \alpha_0, \ldots, \lnot \alpha_n$. By the finiteness theorem we can choose for every $n$ a finite subset $X_n \subset X$ such that $X_n \vdash \lnot \alpha_0, \ldots, \lnot \alpha_n$.

How do I show now that this leads to a contradiction? I.e. I want to show that it follows from the above that $X \cup \{ \lnot \alpha ; \alpha \in Y\}$ is a consistent set.

And how do I treat the case where $Y$ is uncountable?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint* for a possible solution, using the *Natural Deduction* proof system.

I'll make a couple of assumptions :

*(i)* I'll assume the *Natural Deduction* proof system for *classical* logic;

*(ii)* I'll assume the following definition of *inconsistency*; we say that $X$ is *inconsistent* iff : $X \vdash \bot$.

Then, the given is :

> $X \cup \{ \lnot \alpha \} \vdash \bot, \alpha \in Y$.

If so, by $\to$-introduction : $X \vdash \lnot \alpha \to \bot$, i.e., by *Double Negation* :

> > $X \vdash \alpha$.

$\alpha \in Y$, and thus, by $\lor$-introduction : $X \vdash \alpha_0 \lor \ldots \alpha_n$.